# andengine extension errors

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine

I just import andengine using git. fortunately no errors found. However andengine extension has many errors.

```
[2012-09-03 03:02:29 - AndEngineMODPlayerExtension]     (skipping file '.gitignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
[2012-09-03 03:02:29 - AndEngineMODPlayerExtension] ERROR: resource directory 'C:\Documents and Settings\admin\workspace_mobile2\AndEngineMODPlayerExtension\res' does not exist
[2012-09-03 03:05:53 - AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension] ERROR: resource directory 'C:\Documents and Settings\admin\workspace_mobile2\AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension\res' does not exist
[2012-09-03 03:05:54 - AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension] ERROR: resource directory 'C:\Documents and Settings\admin\workspace_mobile2\AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension\res' does not exist
[2012-09-03 03:06:06 - AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension]     (skipping file '.gitignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
[2012-09-03 03:06:06 - AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension] ERROR: resource directory 'C:\Documents and Settings\admin\workspace_mobile2\AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension\res' does not exist
[2012-09-03 03:06:10 - AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension]     (skipping file '.gitignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
[2012-09-03 03:06:10 - AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension] ERROR: resource directory 'C:\Documents and Settings\admin\workspace_mobile2\AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension\res' does not exist
[2012-09-03 03:06:20 - AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension]     (skipping file '.gitignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
[2012-09-03 03:06:20 - AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension] ERROR: resource directory 'C:\Documents and Settings\admin\workspace_mobile2\AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension\res' does not exist
[2012-09-03 03:06:51 - AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension]     (skipping file '.gitignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
[2012-09-03 03:06:51 - AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension] ERROR: resource directory 'C:\Documents and Settings\admin\workspace_mobile2\AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension\res' does not exist
```

I tried creating a res folder but it doesnt works.
That only the livewallpaper library. I havnt imported mod and multiplayer extension and others. Anyone how to fix this problem? Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

This error appears from time to time, but in my case usually disappears after the workspace is rebuilt. Try disabling the 'Build automatically' option and then clean the workspace.